# Python - How to create new Json file after every loop?

Tags: python, json

So I have a CSV file that I convert later on to a JSON file. However what I want to do is that I want to save to a new json file for every json objects that is new. Meaning something like this:

```
{
"first_name": "Hello",
"last_name": "World",
"color": "black"
},

{
"first_name": "Stack",
"last_name": "Overflow",
"color": "Red"
}
```

How I change it to a format from CSV to JSON is that I create it as a dict where I have the CSV format and a fieldsname that is created based on "first_name", "last_name_" and color.

It would look like something like:

```
jsonfile = open('newfilejson.json', 'w')
fieldnames = ("first_name","last_name","color")
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)

for row in reader:
    jsonfile.write('"first_name": "' + row['first_name'] + '",\n')
    jsonfile.write('"last_name": "' + row['last_name'] + '",\n')
    jsonfile.write('"color": "' + row['color'] + '",\n')
```

however this will just save into one file basically and my question is:

How can I make so everytime it finished one "row" from the for-loop to create a new json file that contains whats inside the for-loop (With write) and then whenever there is new, it creates a new json file. Basically meaning that everytime a row is finished, create new json?

Comment: Use an additional `for`-loop around most code (except the two lines for opening the CSV-file)  in which you open, write and _close_ a new JSON-file on each iteration.

Comment: @MichaelButscher But do I need to create the json file before hand to be able to write it?

Comment: Yes, you must first create (and open, which is the same operation here) a file before you can write to it.

Comment: you want to open a json & create another json file for each csv row? or to open a json & make a csv row saved in a json? your explanation & code kind of contradicts each other, i'm confused.

Comment: Do you _really_ want to write a zillion separate JSON files? Why not a single JSON file containing a list of those dict objects?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what your expected output for that file should be. It would make it a lot easier to understand what you want.

Comment: Down below in Answers made by Ralf was exactly what I wanted to wish!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
for row in reader:
    filename = 'a_file_{}'.format(row['first_name'])
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write('"first_name": "' + row['first_name'] + '",\n')
        f.write('"last_name": "' + row['last_name'] + '",\n')
        f.write('"color": "' + row['color'] + '",\n')
```

You just need to decide how these files should be named. My example uses the first name in the filename.

Comment: I used this and it helped me what I wanted to achieve! Thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a context manager to open and write to a new json file for each row:

```
fieldnames = ("first_name","last_name","color")
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)

for row in reader:
    with open('%s_%s.json' % (row['first_name'], row['last_name']), 'w') as jsonfile:
        jsonfile.write('"first_name": "' + row['first_name'] + '",\n')
        jsonfile.write('"last_name": "' + row['last_name'] + '",\n')
        jsonfile.write('"color": "' + row['color'] + '",\n')
```